# How to get COUNT from several tables?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have these data below

```
TABLE 1   SID   CAMBORROW      OTMARK
          S1      CAM1           1
          S2      CAM2           1
          S3      CAM3           0

TABLE 2   SID   BOOKBORROW     OTMARK
          S1     book1           1
          S2     book2           0
          S3     book3           0

TABLE 3   SID     NAME           
          S1     SNAME1
          S2     SNAME2
          S3     SNAME3
```

Now what I want to do is getting how many times does this person have OTMARK 1 on him/her, also group by his/her name. This is what I use for the query.

```
SELECT TABLE3.NAME,COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE1,TABLE2,TABLE3
WHERE TABLE3.SID = TABLE1.SID
AND   TABLE1.OTMARK = 1
OR( TABLE3.SID = TABLE2.SID
   AND TABLE2.OTMARK = 1)
GROUP BY TABLE1.NAME
```

The result I got is far wrong than what should happen. I don't know which part I got it wrong, so I need help. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: The expect output is

```
SNAME   COUNT
SNAME1   2
SNAME2   1
```

Comment: Please show expected output

Comment: @OldProgrammer edited. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `join` the tables with proper `join` syntax.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dff63f/19)

```
SELECT t3.name,
sum(nvl(t1.otmark,0)+nvl(t2.otmark,0))
FROM  table3 t3 
left join table2 t2 on t2.sid = t3.sid  and t2.otmark =1
left join table1 t1 on t1.sid = t3.sid  and t1.otmark =1
where t1.otmark is not null or t2.otmark is not null
GROUP BY t3.NAME
```

Edit: A simpler solution would be

```
SELECT t3.name, t1.otmark+t2.otmark
FROM  t3 
join  t2 on t2.sid = t3.sid
join  t1 on t1.sid = t3.sid
where t1.otmark > 0 or t2.otmark > 0
```

Comment: the OTMARK are not the keys here. I want to get them seperately so I can count them twice.

Comment: @DevArenaCN vkp has already shown how to do it, is it too difficult for you to try?

Comment: @Adish I tried, the result only get me `sname    count
                                                             SNAME1    1`

Comment: modified the query. try the latest one

Comment: @vkp Still with the same result.

Comment: @DevArenaCN I again suggest that you share your query, so we can explain what needs to be modified. Just posting an answer will not be that helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
Select table3.name SNAME,(table2.otmark+table1.otmark) COUNT
From table3 
inner join table2 
on table3.sid=table2.sid 
inner join table1 
on table1.sid=table2.sid
Where table1.otmark>0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should union TABLE1 and TABLE2 to combine the result.

```
SELECT t3.NAME, COUNT(*)
FROM table3 AS t3
LEFT JOIN
  ( SELECT SID, CAMBORROW AS ITEMBORROW, OTMARK 
    FROM table1
    WHERE OTMARK = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SID, BOOKBORROW AS ITEMBORROW, OTMARK 
    FROM table2
    WHERE OTMARK = 1
  ) AS t4
ON t3.SID = t4.SID
GROUP BY t3.NAME;
```

More information about UNION syntax [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/union.html).